Loud vibrating sound when using tub
After installing a new hot water heater, our tub filler started making a very loud jackhammer-like vibrating sound. The sound was not present before we installed the hot water heater, which leads me to believe that something happened accidentally during the install.
More details:

All of the other fixtures in the house work with no noise (including a shower)
The noise starts a few seconds after spinning the valve to use hot water but doesn't seem to happen when using cold water only
The installer (who is a smart generalist and not a plumber) had to fiddle with the grey hotter colder setting (see picture) and the shut off screws (see picture) in order to get any water to come out. When he was here there was no sound, but then after a few uses the sound started happening consistently.
The brand of this value is Hansgrohe
This person had luck turning on other valves but all of my other valves are open (Loud vibrating when using hot water!)

My hunch is that this is something small related to the adjustments and I'd prefer to avoid calling a plumber if possible. Any suggestions?


My first suspicion would be debris stuck in the valve.
Hopefully you have, or can find online, the installation manual for this valve.  They will contain instructions for flushing the valve during installation.  You can follow the installation instructions in reverse to get to that stage, and flush it.
The general steps are:

Cover the drain so you don't lose small parts
Turn off the water using the two shutoff valves there.
Remove the valve stem, inspect it and clean it.  You might see the debris, or it might fall out or fall down the pipe towards the bath spout when you remove the valve.  Doesn't matter.
Turn each water valves on, gently and one by one, to flush out the valve body
Put it all back together, following the instructions carefully to assemble and adjust its temperature.

The vibration will hopefully be gone, but don't stop yet:

If the bath spout has an aerator, remove it, clean it and flush out the spout before replacing it.
Remove all shower heads and clean them paying special attention to debris stuck in the flow limiters.  Work in a bucket or a sink with the drain covered.

Don't work straight off this post; find the instructions!
